# autocomplete is undefined with material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code in a jsx file and I get error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: AutoComplete is not defined

From what I see it should be working ok, Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Autocomplete }   from 'material-ui';

class MaterialUIAutocomplete extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onUpdateInput = this.onUpdateInput.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dataSource : [],
      inputValue : ''
    }
  }

  onUpdateInput(inputValue) {
  }

  render() {
    return <AutoComplete
            dataSource    = {this.state.dataSource}
            onUpdateInput = {this.onUpdateInput} />
  }
}

export default MaterialUIAutocomplete;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a typo, you are importing `Autocomplete` and using `AutoComplete`.

Use these ways to `import AutoComplete`:

```
import { AutoComplete } from 'material-ui';
```

Or

```
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
```

**Update:**

To render material-ui component we need to add the default theme and styling, include these lines in your component, like this:

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({});
```

Then render the `AutoComplete` inside `MuiThemeProvider`:

```
render() {
    return <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
              <AutoComplete
                  dataSource    = {this.state.dataSource}
                  onUpdateInput = {this.onUpdateInput} />
           </MuiThemeProvider>
}
```

Use this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({});

class MaterialUIAutocomplete extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          dataSource : [],
          inputValue : ''
        }
        this.onUpdateInput = this.onUpdateInput.bind(this);
    }

    onUpdateInput(inputValue) {
    }

    render() {
        return <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>
                  <AutoComplete
                      dataSource    = {this.state.dataSource}
                      onUpdateInput = {this.onUpdateInput} />
             </MuiThemeProvider>
    }
}

export default MaterialUIAutocomplete;
```

**Note:** `MuiThemeProvider` is not required to include inside each component, you can use this in main page and then you can use any material-ui component inside any component.

Comment: oh boy!  Thank you so much.  Now I am getting the error of  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined"

Comment: i think that error is coming from some other component, because in this part, you are not using `prepareStyles`, check the place where you are using that. I guess that is `binding issue`, somewhere you forgot to `bind` any method.

Comment: There are no other components that I am using.

Comment: are you using `prepareStyles` in this component ?

Comment: it is in the material-ui file.

Comment: so you are suggesting that the binding issue is in the material-ui file then if I am understanding it correctly?

Comment: these are the two places where it is being used                                                           var prepareStyles = this.context.muiTheme.prepareStyles;

Comment: style: prepareStyles((0, _simpleAssign2.default)(styles.root, style)) },
        _react2.default.createElement(_TextField2.default, (0, _extends3.default)({
          ref: 'searchTextField',
          autoComplete: 'off',
          onBlur: this.handleBlur,
          onFocus: this.handleFocus,
          onKeyDown: this.handleKeyDown,
          floatingLabelText: floatingLabelText,
          hintText: hintText,
          fullWidth: fullWidth,
          multiLine: false,
          errorStyle: errorStyle,
          style: textFieldStyle

Comment: no i was guessing that because i thought you are using that in some other component, `MuiThemeProvider` is required to provide the theme to material-ui components. is it working now?

Comment: nope.  new errors "Failed Context Types: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the `prop-types` package. Use `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()` to call them. " and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepareStyles' of undefined"

Comment: where do I put this?

Comment: updated the answer with complete code try the same code, it should work.

Comment: now I am throwing 3 new errors.  "Warning: Failed Context Types: Calling PropTypes validators directly is not supported by the `prop-types` package. Use `PropTypes.checkPropTypes()` to call them." 
 and "Warning: Material-UI: We don't have enough information
      to build a robust unique id for the TextField component. Please provide an id or a name." and "Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's `render` method"

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a migration issue to me - you want to use the material-ui 0.x AutoComplete, but you have installed the new material-ui v1.x.
as such, you need to follow the Migration steps and in order to use any v0.x component, put this wherever you create/declare your themes:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
 <V0MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={themeV0}>
   {/*Components*/}
 </V0MuiThemeProvider>
```

Because the new 1.5 theme is available via props, the old one through context, you need to include both for AutoComplete to have reference to the old theme. I wouldn't do this unless you really need something from the old library, such as the AutoComplete widget.

https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v0x/